# Hiding one textbox in the table header when it is not in the first page

Tags: reporting-services

Help me please. This thing drive me crazy. It really should be a simple solution but I can't find it, even with Googling.

I have a subreport that display deposit transaction banking statement from account (customer).

This subreport will be accessed through main report that loop all accounts in one branch, so it's like a batch report processing for all customer in a branch. Rendered to pdf and distributed to all our branches.

Since I know that subreports header footer won't work on main report, I decide to move the subreport header into subreport table header and make it looks like it was a report header. But this is one problem I can't solve: there is **address box** that should only visible on **first** page for each customer, along with the other header that always visible.

And this will be printed on pre-printed paper, so I cant make the address box outside the other header since the report would be shrunk, without the address box, at page 2 and the rest of the pages from each customer, which will make the table header and the content go up and the positions will not match with our pre-printed paper borders anymore.

What am I supposed to do? Please help, I've been searching andn trying for 3 days and can't find any working solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? For example, do you want to leave a clear space the same size as the address box on pages 2 onwards, for each customer?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

1. Set the subreport table header **row** property RepeatOnNewPage to be True (in the Properties window).
2. Set the subreport table header **cells** Visibility>Hidden property for the address box cells to be a formula that evaluates to False for the first page, and True for all subsequent pages, such as:

   `If PageNumber = 1 Then False Else True`

This should ensure that the table header is printed on every page, with a blank section the size of the address box included on all pages after the first page.

Answer (score 0):

yes. 
the address box is only at first page for each customer since it is for posting address. i cant tolerate address box in each pages of each customer because it would be very awkward.
and i have to maintain the space on page 2 onwards so the report don't collapse (header going up of the paper) and not match with our already-printed (already have company logo and borders) papers.